# Nested Map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hashmap, nested

What I trying to do is when I have

```
rec1 = [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")]
```

then I would like to have

```
[( "us", [("up", [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")])])]
```

This is the code that I have come up with in Haskell.

```
rec1 = [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")] 
convertto rec = Prelude.foldl (\map (k, v) -> Data.Map.insert k v map) Data.Map.empty rec 
justfold = Prelude.foldr (\key val -> Data.Map.insert key val Data.Map.empty) (convertto rec1) ["us","up"]
```

In my third line above, in my lambda function definition, the compiler is not agreeing with the type of val. It is saying it expects a Char and is getting a String or not able to match Map String with list type.

I am not really good with Haskell, so looking if anybody could give me pointers to it.

Thanks.

EDIT: corrected the output type. I mistyped it at first.

Comment: Sorry, but I think your explanation of what you want to achieve is not clear. In particular you cannot have something like [ "us", [("up", [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")])]] because all elements of the list need to be of the same type.

Comment: Apologies, I corrected the output type, I want. What I want is a nested hash map. Does the new output type make sense.

Comment: Pretty sure nothing you're using here is a hashmap...

Comment: I have not included the import Data.Map in my code sample above, just to keep it short. If Data.Map is not a kind of hash map, then what in Haskell would give me map or hash map?

Comment: Not all maps are hashmaps as your comment may suggest. Hashmap uses hashes to index stuff, regular map usually uses some fancy balanced tree to allow fast, though not constant access time.

Comment: I am not really interested in performance or memory optimizations. I just want a map on which I can do a key value look up, and which is nested.

Comment: Then Data.Map is what you want (it is a tree map though, not a hash map).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code, some easy, and some hard. Let's examine the easy ones first:

The first is your `convertto` function. It exists already, and is called `fromList`. There's also a function for creating a new `Map` with one pair in it, called `singleton`. Also the way you're referring to functions in `Data.Map` is unusual. Fixing these issues gives:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

rec1 = M.fromList [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")] 
justfold = foldr M.singleton rec1 ["us","up"]
```

Now however, there's a deeper problem. To figure out what it is, let's try adding type signatures to `rec1` and `justfold`:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

rec1 :: M.Map [Char] [Char]
rec1 = M.fromList [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")] 

justfold :: M.Map [Char] (M.Map [Char] (M.Map [Char] [Char]))
justfold = foldr M.singleton rec1 ["us","up"]
```

`rec1` is just fine, but `justfold` is a problem. To see why, look at the type signatures of `foldr` and `singleton`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

singleton :: k -> a -> Map k a
```

`foldr` requires a function of type `(a -> b -> b)`, and `singleton` is not that, because `a` and `Map k a` are not the same thing. The following code produces the result you want:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

rec1 = M.fromList [("name", "obj-1"), ("status", "up"), ("region", "us")] 
justfold = M.singleton "us" $ M.singleton "up" rec1
```

However, the fundamental issue is that you can't iterate over something that changes type on every iteration. If you find yourself wanting to do this, I advise you to take a step back and rethink your approach to the problem.

Comment: I got what you said, and am trying to define my own data type, so I can fix the lambda to fit with the foldr. I got the problem, once I pruned the code as per suggestions, and tried again. Thanks for the help.